# Why is +False not False in Python?

Tags: python, object, boolean

I was checking some of CPython's tests and in this [file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/test/test_bool.py#L45) I saw a test case which was strange to me:

```
def test_math(self):
    ...
    self.assertIsNot(+False, False)
```

At first I thought it is a typo and it should be `self.assertIs(+False, False)` but when I tried it on the Python console the result was `False`:

```
>>> +False is False
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
False
>>> 
>>> id(False)
140078839501184
>>> id(+False)
140078839621760
```

Why does `+` make it a different object?

Comments suggest that `+False` is `0`. So maybe the better question should be why is this?

Comment: `False` is `False` and `+False` is `0`.

Comment: You should print `+False` at least once.

Comment: `+False` gives 0, like `+True` gives 1.

Comment: The `is` operator is very unreliable for numbers and strings since it will check the memory location of the object. `0 == False` as expected.

Comment: @luk2302 Why `+False` is `0`?

Comment: `+False == 0` because in python booleans are considered special integers. You can also do `-True == -1` or `True + False == 1` for example.

Comment: @mousetail As far as I know `False` numerical value is always `0`. But why does `+False` change it?

Comment: The `+` operator can be used to convert things to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `bool` is a type of `int`:

```
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

a bool is accepted by functions that take ints as inputs (including all the standard operators), and those functions will generally return ints:

```
>>> True + False
1
>>> True * 2
2
>>> True ** False
1
```

or sometimes floats:

```
>>> True / True
1.0
```

Specifically, putting `+` in front of a number is a "unary plus", the opposite of a "unary minus" which returns the negative of its operand:

```
>>> +True
1
>>> -True
-1
>>> +False
0
>>> -False
0
```

Although this bool/int behavior catches most people off guard the first time they find it, it allows for some useful shortcuts; for example, you can `sum` a bunch of bools to find the number of `True` values:

```
>>> sum([True, True, False, False, True])
3
>>> sum(s.startswith("a") for s in ("apple", "banana", "pear", "avocado"))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply arithmetic operations to boolean values they are turned into `int`.

```
In [10]: type(+False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[10]: int

In [11]: type(False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[11]: bool
```